# Powershell script is changing the filepath to C:\Windows\system32

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have Powershell ISE open as Administrator. When I execute the script from the desktop (e.g. `C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\CompareScripts\runCompareScript.ps1`), the script works fine. However, when I execute from the `C:\CompareScripts\runCompareScript.ps1` the script changes the file path to `C:\Windows\system32\runCompareScript.ps1`. Why is this occurring and how can I prevent this from happening?

> **Note:** This is happening during the execution of a `invoke-sqlcmd`
>   statement.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear how you execute your script and it shouldn't change to `C:\windows...`, you can use `$pwd` for the current directory, to access data files in the user directory use: `$env:UserProfile\Desktop\CompareScripts\foo.sql` You may need to show more of your script for us to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current working directory is changing as you change contexts. Use the absolute file path.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\CompareScripts\---.sql"
```

Comment: Why can't I do something a little more dynamic? Right now I'm using the following `$rootDir = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition;` to get the current working directory. I know the statement works, because the extractRSPath in the above screenshot is correct yet the error thrown is not.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on line 128 and run $extractPath when execution pauses, I guarantee the output is 'C:\Windows\system32\---.sql'. I can't explain why that is without seeing the script. With the information available, the best solution is to use an absolute path.

Comment: @PhiL `$rootDir` is the location of your script, not your working directory. Compare the output of `$rootDir` and `$PWD.Path`. You can build an absolute path for the invoked script like this: `Join-Path $rootDir 'something.sql'`.

Comment: Thanks guys!. When Powershell ISE is initially opened the default working directory is `C:\Windows\system32` and the statement that was causing the issue was in terms of a relative path (e.g. `$sqlPath = $sqlScript`). To resolve the issue, I changed it to `$sqlPath = $rootDir + $sqlScript`.